# how to assign NULL type for int type in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Follow my code

```
begin
    declare @Iorder int 
    set @Iorder=0
    declare @no int
    set @no=(select MAX(IOrder) from Team)
    if @no=NULL
        set @Iorder=1
    else
        begin 
            set @Iorder=(select MAX(IOrder) from Team)
            set @Iorder=@Iorder+1
        end 
end
```

if in Team table has no row `select MAX(IOrder) from Team` statement return `NULL` value so statement `if @no=NULL` is not correct because `@no` is `int` type then SQL Server return a error `Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.`
So how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test using `is null` instead.

```
begin
    declare @Iorder int 
    set @Iorder=0
    declare @no int
    set @no=(select MAX(IOrder) from Team)
    if @no is null
        set @Iorder=1
    else
        begin 
            set @Iorder=(select MAX(IOrder) from Team)
            set @Iorder=@Iorder+1
        end 
end
```

Your code can be rewritten using `isnull()` instead.

```
declare @Iorder int 
select @Iorder = 1 + isnull(max(IOrder), 0) from Team
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this all in a short form.

Try this:

```
begin
    declare @Iorder int 
    SELECT @Iorder = ISNULL(MAX(IOrder),0)+1 FROM Team
end
```

**Explanation:**

`@Iorder` will be 1 (i.e., 0+1) if `MAX(IOrder)` is NULL.

Otherwise, `@Iorder` will be `MAX(IOrder)+1`.

Comment: @TienKenji: Feel free to accept the answer, then. If you don't know how to accept an answer, please [**read this**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

Use `SELECT ISNULL(MAX(IOrder),0) FROM Team` (Returns 0 in case of null) and remove the if else to check null values, `SELECT ISNULL(MAX(IOrder),0) + 1  FROM Team` in case you want incremented value